# How to give dynamic value for path in testng.xml

Tags: java, testng

I have created a class for reading the excel values which is in one package and there is one more class to check login which is in different class in the form of testng.
My ReadExcelFile.java is 
package uat;

```
public class ReadExcelFile extends BeforeAfterSuite{

    @Test
    @Parameters("filename")
    public void readXLSXFile(String fileName)   {
        InputStream XlsxFileToRead = null;
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = null;
        try {
            XlsxFileToRead = new FileInputStream(fileName);

            //Getting the workbook instance for xlsx file
            workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(XlsxFileToRead);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //getting the first sheet from the workbook using sheet name. 
        // We can also pass the index of the sheet which starts from '0'.
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("Sheet1");
        XSSFRow row;
        XSSFCell cell;

        //Iterating all the rows in the sheet
        Iterator rows = sheet.rowIterator();

        while (rows.hasNext()) {
            row = (XSSFRow) rows.next();

            //Iterating all the cells of the current row
            Iterator cells = row.cellIterator();

            while (cells.hasNext()) {
                cell = (XSSFCell) cells.next();

                if (cell.getCellType() == XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                    System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + " ");
                } else if (cell.getCellType() == XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
                    System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + " ");
                } else if (cell.getCellType() == XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN) {
                    System.out.print(cell.getBooleanCellValue() + " ");

                } 
            }
            System.out.println();
            try {
                XlsxFileToRead.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }



}
```

and in testng I want to pass the parameter as filename along with the path but is hardcoded instead I want to send dynamic value 

because the location I intend to later on move is in shared path.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you do it

- Remove the dependency on `@Parameters`
- Leverage a JVM argument say `filename` to optionally accept the actual location and if not provided define a default value for the JVM argument.

Your code can look like below

```
@Test
public void readXLSXFile()   {
    //To provide a different value for the excel sheet, use the JVM argument: -Dfilename
    //For e.g., -Dfilename=src/test/resources/anotherdata.xls
    //If this JVM argument is not provided, 
    //then the file name is defaulted to src/test/resources/data.xls
    String fileName = System.getProperty("filename", "src/test/resources/data.xls");
    InputStream XlsxFileToRead = null;
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = null;
    //Rest of the code goes here
}
```